# How to prove Cauchy-Schwarz inequality using multivariable calculus?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

How would I prove that for standard inner product on $\mathbb{R^2}$:

where $\langle v,w\rangle := \sum_{i=1}^2 v_i \cdot w_i$,

$$(v_1w_1 + v_2w_2)^2 \le (v_1^2 +v_2^2)(w_1^2+w_2^2)$$

Hint we were given: $$f(v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2) = (v_1^2 +v_2^2)(w_1^2+w_2^2) - (v_1w_1 + v_2w_2)^2$$

Comment: $$(v_1^2 +v_2^2)(w_1^2+w_2^2)-(v_1w_1 + v_2w_2)^2 =(v_1w_2-w_1v_2)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We need to find te global minimum of

$$f(v_1, v_2, w_1, w_2) = (v_1^2 +v_2^2)(w_1^2+w_2^2) - (v_1w_1 + v_2w_2)^2$$

Comment: What do I do once I've found the global minimum?

Comment: We need to show that $f\ge 0$ with $f=0 \iff v_1=kw_1$ and $v_2=kw_2$.

Comment: @NicoleBotha Are you forced to use that method?

Comment: Yes I am forced to use that method

Comment: @NicoleBotha Then we need to proceed finding critical points. It seems not so trivial at a first sight! Good luck!